# How to Implement EXM Custom Unsubscribe from Email Campaign

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm

Will redirect to the same link `Unsubscribe.aspx`, wanna add some functionality when the user clicks **Unsubscribe** or **UnsubscribeFromAll**.
I created a Class inherited from `IClientApiService` and add Config File but still it does not work.

my scenario that I need to run my pipeline After running reDirectUrl pipeline

```
 public class CustomUnsubscribe : IClientApiService
    {
      public void UpdateListSubscription(UpdateListSubscriptionMessage message)
        {
           
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
   }
```

**Config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <group groupName="exm.messageEvents">
                <pipelines>
                    <redirectUrl>
                        <processor type="FormsExtension.Pipelines.CustomUnsubscribe, FormsExtension.Pipelines" resolve="true">
                        <!--<processor type="Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Pipelines.RedirectUrl.CustomUnsubscribe, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd" resolve="true">-->
                            <!--<internalCarryoverFields hint="list:AddInternalCarryoverField">
                                <patch:delete />
                            </internalCarryoverFields>-->
                        </processor>
                    </redirectUrl>
                </pipelines>
            </group>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19932/how-to-configure-a-custom-exm-unsubscribe-page

Comment: I used the same config as this link, still facing the same problem, I updated my Question